# Customize the URL hit from ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, activeresource

I have an application `App2` to which I am sending a `POST` request from `App1` using `ActiveResource`.

On the `App1`,
I have

```
module App2
    class Iteeem # Purposely misspelled here
        def self.edit_item
            self.prefix "/api/editing_item/"
            post :item, {:property => {:value => 5665}}
        end
    end
end
```

It hits

```
http://app2.mydomain.com/api/editing_item/iteeems/item.xml
```

(Now you know why I misspelt it)

But I want it to hit

```
http://app2.mydomain.com/api/editing_item/item.xml
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, got it moments after I posted this!
Just replace the trailing slash

replace

```
self.prefix "/api/editing_item/"
```

with

```
self.prefix "/api/editing_item"
```

and add

```
self.element_name ""
```

Hope this helps someone...